# in java,how to get file name in the thread

Tags: java, logging

I have an `ArrayList` called `fileList`. It contains a list of file names. Through the for loop, I am creating the thread for every file name and monitoring the file by using `TailListener` Java API. Now I want to get the file name for each message present in the files.

```
fileListener= new fileListener();

for(int i=0;i<fileList.Size();i++)
{           
   monitorFile(filelist.get(i));            
}

private void monitorFile(String logFile) {

         File pcounter_log = new File(logFile);

         Tailer = new Tailer(pcounter_log, fileListener, 5000);   

         ThreadPoolExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(Tailer, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    }


public class fileListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {

String s= "abc";

    public void handle(String line) {

            if(line.contains(s)){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
    }
}
```

In the above code, how do I get the file name for the corresponding log messages?

Comment: What corresponding log messages? I'm afraid your question is far from clear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question to give more information.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way would be to use separate listeners for each file:

Change your `fileListener` class to something like this:

```
public class FileListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {

    private final String fileName;

    public FileListener(String fileName) {
         this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void handle(String line) {
         if(line.contains(s)){
             System.out.println(fileName + ": " + line);
         }
    }
}
```

Then simply instantiate a new `FileListener` for each file you monitor:

```
private void monitorFile(String logFile) {
     File pcounter_log = new File(logFile);
     Tailer = new Tailer(pcounter_log, new FileListener(logFile), 5000);   
     ThreadPoolExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(Tailer, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
}
```